# Selenium(OSX and Linux) thowing error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error only in OSX and Linux but Windows OS it is working fine

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'

Selenium Version: 3.11.0
Chrome Version: 79.0.3945.130
Chrome driver version: 79.0.3945.36

Below are the chrome options in my code. Please let me know if you ever come across this problem

```
case GlobalProperties.CHROME:
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    PropertiesRepository.getString("global.browser.chrome.driver.executable"));
            cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setBrowserName(
                    PropertiesRepository.getString("global.browser.capability.browserName.ch"));
            cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            cap.setCapability("platform",
                    PropertiesRepository.getString("global.browser.capability.platform"));
            cap.setCapability("takesScreenshot", PropertiesRepository
                    .getBoolean("global.browser.capability.chrome.takesScreenshot"));
            cap.setCapability("handlesAlerts", PropertiesRepository
                    .getBoolean("global.browser.capability.chrome.handlesAlerts"));
            cap.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", PropertiesRepository
                    .getBoolean("global.browser.capability.chrome.cssSelectorsEnabled"));
            // Clearing session. 
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

            // Opening incognito browser for clear cache. 
            cap.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));

            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
            prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            prefs.put("download.default_directory",
                    PropertiesRepository.getString("global.download.location"));

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions"); // To "Disable developer mode extensions"
            options.addArguments("--test-type");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); //to disable browser extension popup
            options.addArguments("--incognito");
            options.addArguments("--no-sanbox");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.setBinary("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
            String extensions = PropertiesRepository
                    .getString("global.browser.capability.chrome.extensions");
            if (extensions != null && !extensions.trim().equals("")) {
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(extensions, ",");
                String extensionPath = PropertiesRepository
                        .getString("global.browser.capability.chrome.extensionpath");
                File[] extFiles = new File[tokens.countTokens()];
                int i = 0;
                while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
                    extFiles[i] = new File(extensionPath + "/" + tokens.nextToken());
                    i++;
                }
                options.addExtensions(extFiles);
            }

            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            break;
```

**EXCEPTION**

```
BROWSER : chrome
Jan 25, 2020 2:52:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (DriverFactory.java:58) - Desired Capabilities : Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: [--incognito], cssSelectorsEnabled: true, ensureCleanSession: true, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [disable-infobars, chrome.switches, --disable-extensions, --test-type, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --no-sanbox, --headless], binary: /Applications/Google Chrome..., extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:/download/ASMT, download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: WINDOWS, takesScreenshot: true, version: }
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (DriverFactory.java:63) - environment value ==> stage
 INFO [pool-1-thread-3] (DriverFactory.java:58) - Desired Capabilities : Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: [--incognito], cssSelectorsEnabled: true, ensureCleanSession: true, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [disable-infobars, chrome.switches, --disable-extensions, --test-type, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --no-sanbox, --headless], binary: /Applications/Google Chrome..., extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:/download/ASMT, download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: WINDOWS, takesScreenshot: true, version: }
 INFO [pool-1-thread-3] (DriverFactory.java:63) - environment value ==> stage
Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 21174
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1579985542.015][WARNING]: FromSockAddr failed on netmask
ERROR [pool-1-thread-2] (BaseTest.java:55) - Unable to load Driver
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'ASC-C02YQ2BYLVDQ.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c07:496e:1e2d:7ea7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver                        0x000000011001ce29 chromedriver + 3817001
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010ffb0f33 chromedriver + 3374899
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010fd318bf chromedriver + 755903
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010fcbc19e chromedriver + 274846
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010fcbb9d2 chromedriver + 272850
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010fcbce7d chromedriver + 278141
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010fcb9fa3 chromedriver + 266147
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010fc93c0d chromedriver + 109581
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010fc94ba5 chromedriver + 113573
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010ffdef6f chromedriver + 3563375
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010ffebe3a chromedriver + 3616314
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010ffebbf7 chromedriver + 3615735
12  chromedriver                        0x000000010ffbe699 chromedriver + 3430041
13  chromedriver                        0x000000010ffec692 chromedriver + 3618450
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010ffd2e17 chromedriver + 3513879
15  chromedriver                        0x0000000110001fe4 chromedriver + 3706852
16  chromedriver                        0x0000000110022fc7 chromedriver + 3841991
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff715812eb _pthread_body + 126
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71584249 _pthread_start + 66
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7158040d thread_start + 13

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.driver.DriverFactory$1.initialValue(DriverFactory.java:97)
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.driver.DriverFactory$1.initialValue(DriverFactory.java:37)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.driver.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:111)
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.test.BaseTest.setup(BaseTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:517)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (BaseTest.java:59) - Method name in Base Test in setup for loading properties:ASMT746_VerifyQuizBankAndItsElements
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (PropertiesRepository.java:86) - List of files to load : stg_input.properties
 INFO [pool-1-thread-2] (PropertiesRepository.java:33) - Loading property file : stg_input.properties
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.test.ExtentReport.takesScreenshot(ExtentReport.java:101)
    at com.ascendlearning.automation.ui.test.ExtentReport.onConfigurationFailure(ExtentReport.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runConfigurationListeners(Invoker.java:1770)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleConfigurationFailure(Invoker.java:303)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:237)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:845)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1153)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue myself where desired capabilities still pointing to WINDOWS OS properties for platform and default download directory.  Hence i have modified the code to set these values based on the OS that resolved the issue.

Desired Capabilities :

```
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: [--incognito], cssSelectorsEnabled: true, ensureCleanSession: true, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [disable-infobars, chrome.switches, --disable-extensions, --test-type, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --no-sanbox, --headless], binary: /Applications/Google Chrome..., extensions: [], prefs: {**download.default_directory: C:/download/ASMT**, download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, **platform: WINDOWS**, takesScreenshot: true, version: }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Jan 25, 2020 2:52:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (DriverFactory.java:58) - Desired Capabilities : Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: [--incognito], cssSelectorsEnabled: true, ensureCleanSession: true, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [disable-infobars, chrome.switches, --disable-extensions, --test-type, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --no-sanbox, --headless], binary: /Applications/Google Chrome..., extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:/download/ASMT, download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: WINDOWS, takesScreenshot: true, version: }
 INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (DriverFactory.java:63) - environment value ==> stage
 INFO [pool-1-thread-3] (DriverFactory.java:58) - Desired Capabilities : Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, chrome.switches: [--incognito], cssSelectorsEnabled: true, ensureCleanSession: true, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [disable-infobars, chrome.switches, --disable-extensions, --test-type, --disable-extensions, --incognito, --no-sanbox, --headless], binary: /Applications/Google Chrome..., extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:/download/ASMT, download.prompt_for_download: false, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, handlesAlerts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: WINDOWS, takesScreenshot: true, version: }
 INFO [pool-1-thread-3] (DriverFactory.java:63) - environment value ==> stage
Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}) on port 21174
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1579985542.015][WARNING]: FromSockAddr failed on netmask
ERROR [pool-1-thread-2] (BaseTest.java:55) - Unable to load Driver
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'ASC-C02YQ2BYLVDQ.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1c07:496e:1e2d:7ea7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver                        0x000000011001ce29 chromedriver + 3817001
1   chromedriver                        0x000000010ffb0f33 chromedriver + 3374899
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010fd318bf chromedriver + 755903
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=79.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=79.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 79**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.11.0* of *2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z* which is almost **2** years older.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.11.0* and *chromedriver=79.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I have upgraded to selenium 3.141.59 with all the solution you proposed, it didnt work as I a getting same error